# JS Cannot read property "length" of undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to create an object using a given string where each word has a property stating its length.

```
var strings = {};

function findLongestWord(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
     strings[splitStr[i]] = splitStr[i].length;
  }

  return strings;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I end up getting:

```
"TypeError": Cannot read property "length" of undefined.
```

If I were to replace splitStr[i].length with splitStr[0].length, the code runs properly, but of course giving me the same number for each word in the object.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It should be `i < str.length`. It's off by one.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing with the loop. splitStr is your list of words, yet you iterate on the original string? there aren't nearly as many words as there are characters in str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looping over wrong array. you should use `i < splitStr.length`.

```
  var strings = {};    
  function findLongestWord(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++){
     strings[splitStr[i]] = splitStr[i].length;
  }

  return strings;
}
```