# Parse JSON formatted result of HTTP request into columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Apps Script to pull data from API. I'd like to parse out the information according to the relevant headers.

```js
function Fraud2() {
  var ret = "no value";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://fraudshield.24metrics.com/api/v1/reports/fraud.json?tracker_id=905&group[]=sub_id&group[]=partner&date_start=2018-01-18&date_end=2018-01-18&timezone=UTC&user_id=XXX&api_token=XXX",{muteHttpExceptions:true})
  var user_id = "XXX";
  var api_token = "XXX";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([response]);
}
```

The return is pushed into one single cell like so:

```
 {"results":[{"tracker_id":905,"conversion":7883,"click":0,"goal":0,"approved":6511,"rejected":1372,"tracker":"Tatoo
 Integration","conversion_rate":"N\/A"},{"tracker_id":906,"conversion":1868,"click":0,"goal":0,"approved":1682,"rejected":186,"tracker":"Aise
 Integration","conversion_rate":"N\/A"},{"tracker_id":933,"conversion":413,"click":0,"goal":0,"rejected":290,"approved":123,"tracker":"Tatoo
 Invalids Integration","conversion_rate":"N\/A"}]}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997748/parse-received-information-into-columns-rows) without success.

How can I get the results arranged neatly into columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hink said, you need to convert the object to an array first.

Hinks solution will work fine but below is a combination of the code you tried to use in your post.

```
 function Fraud2() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var ret = "no value";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://fraudshield.24metrics.com/api/v1/reports/fraud.json?tracker_id=905&group[]=sub_id&group[]=partner&date_start=2018-01-18&date_end=2018-01-18&timezone=UTC&user_id=XXX&api_token=XXX",{muteHttpExceptions:true})

    var user_id = "XXX";
    var api_token = "XXX";

  var out=JSON.stringify(response.results);
      out=JSON.parse(out)

  var title = [];
   for (var i in out[0]) {
     title.push(i);
    }
      var res = [];
      res.push(title);
    for (var i in out) {
      var values = [];
    for (var j in out[i]) {
      values.push(out[i][j]);
    }
   res.push(values);
  }

 ss.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
};
```

Comment: The only issue is that the script is supposed to be dynamic. How can I fix that? The values are locked in the code, whereas the updated values should be delivered through the API.

Comment: I've modified the code to work with the code you've posted above but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the response object into an array and append the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++){
  var current = response.results[i];
  var myArray = [current.tracker_id, current.conversion, current.click, current.goal, current.approved, current.rejected, current.tracker,current.conversion_rate];
  sheet.appendRow(myArray);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")

I've tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916065/js-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) But cannot make it work.